# Capitalise SQL Server 2008 keywords

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to capitalise all the letters that are SQL keywords. For example, if I write this:

```
Select *
From EmpMast
```

I want it to become:

```
SELECT *
FROM Empmast
```

How should I do that?

Comment: Do you really mean to change `EmpMast` to `Empmast`? That would be a bug, since your usage of object names should be always case sensitive, in case you application gets deployed on a server or database with a case sensitive collation.

Comment: As a curiosity, why is it important to do this?

Comment: As part of our coding/naming conventions we used to have a rule to capitalize SQL statements. We followed the rule for years. One day one team member proposed not to capitalize, as this capitalization require extra effort while typing SQL. Everybody agreed right away, with absolutely no arguing (which doesn't happen very often). Now everybody is so happy that we switched to the lower case. Although this naming convention is not exactly what you can see in Microsoft SQL samples, but we find lower case easier to use.

Answer (score 6):

If you are typing this code into the Query editor window, this task would be performed by a third-party tool.  Personally, I would suggest one of the tools from RedGate software.  It is called SQL Prompt.  It helps you write your SQL queries.  It is an invaluable tool.  Here is a link to it:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/

Comment: thnks, it's rock , do u have full version?

Comment: +1 for SQL Prompt - excellent tool, well worth its license price - can't be without it anymore!

Comment: @HMD - I do own the full version of SQL Prompt.  It is an amazing tool that will take your SQL development to the next level.  I was always a "text file purist" in my development.  I hand-coded everything without help so I was a bit skeptical of this tool.  However, when I started using it I was amazed at how much faster I could work.  For example, when I do a select statement, it gives me a list of possible fields to choose from.  I can just click and add them.  It will expand it out with every column name.  *For the record, I am not affiliated with RedGate in any way beyond being a customer*